# Quicksort not working

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

This is all my code for my quicksort method, it works on a set of 21 numbers, but not on my real data set, which is about 100000. I have no idea what is wrong, I've been fiddling for two hours and it is due soon! Any help would be very welcome

```
public static void hybridQuicksort( int[] a, int start, int end )
{
    final int MIN = 13;
    if ( end - start >= MIN )
    {
        int pivot = findPivot( a, start, end );
        pivot = partition ( a, start, end, pivot );
        hybridQuicksort( a, start, pivot - 1 );
        hybridQuicksort( a, pivot + 1, end);
    }
    else
    {
        insertionSort( a, start, end );
    }
}

//partitions the array based on the pivot
public static int partition( int[] a, int start, int end, int pivot )
{
    int up = start + 1;
    int down = end;

    while ( up <= down )
    {

        while ( a[up] <= pivot)
            up++;

        while ( a[down] > pivot)
            down--;

        if ( up <= down )
            swap( a, up, down );
    }

    swap( a, start, down );

    return up;
}

//finds the first, middle, middle of first and middle, middle of middle and last
//and last numbers and sets their median as the pivot
public static int findPivot( int[] a, int start, int end )
{
    //swap the 4 numbers to the start of the array, leaving the first as is
    swap( a, start + 1, end - 1 );
    swap( a, start + 2, (start + end) / 2);
    swap( a, start + 3, end / 4);
    swap( a, start + 4, (end / 2) + (end / 4) );

    //sort the 5 numbers
    insertionSort( a, 0, 5 );

    //swap the median to the front, that's the pivot
    swap( a, start, start + 2 );
    //return the pivot
    return a[start];
}
```

Comment: This is not really a place for solving homework questions; especially ones that are nearly due. Perhaps you should ask a class mate or look over some of the qsort tutorials online.

Comment: If you will look at the code, you will notice it is complete, so no one is 'solving' my homework problem. I've done nearly all of it, there is just some glitch in there that I can't seem to find so I was hoping someone would take a glance and see if they can find it. Is that wrong?

Comment: Actually, I take what I said back; while the median of 5 insert sort was/is still wrong, that it was a partitioning problem isn't it (I lost sight of bits of code); lexu is right though.

Comment: Curious: What exactly is the assignment? Your title says Quicksort, but your method is called hybridQuicksort. Which sorting methods did the assignment specify?

Comment: http://pastebin.org/45362

pastebin, for your easy reading pleasure :)

Comment: once you understand the algorithm, you can find code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740183/quicksort-with-first-element-as-pivot-example/12308930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption:

- a holds 10'000 samples,
- start is 500
- end is 1000

  ```
  //swap the 4 numbers to the start of the array, leaving the first as is
  swap( a, start + 1, end - 1 );
  swap( a, start + 2, end / 2);
  swap( a, start + 3, end / 4);
  swap( a, start + 4, (end / 2) + (end / 4) );
  ```

end/4 is 250

.. **you are swapping values from outside your sorting-subset**.

Comment: Ian gave me the idea, today when I open it up again I'm going to pass in a 'interval range' so it will fix that! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a homework problem. Were it a homework problem, the author would have written about seven to ten lines of code, with a proof of effectiveness, and turned it in. This guy is trying to be fancy, and it's biting him in the backside. You can tell by the way he drops to insertion-sort for so-called "small" intervals. (Clue: the threshold interval size is more than half the test data size. Give your algorithm some room to recurse if you want to test it well.) Second, there is the extra work he's doing to find an ideal pivot. This kind of complexity comes at a cost.

This is a hobbyist at work. What he needs is not just an answer. He needs an approach to solving hard problems. Quicksort is just the vehicle for that education.

Here's my approach.

The trick is to write Quicksort as Quicksort, get it working, and then worry about fancy special tricks. Kill off the noise about insertion sorting small intervals. Just assume that any interval of size zero or one is already sorted (which is your base case) and then work on making your partitioning code work using the left end of the interval as the pivot (as in classical original Quicksort), and you might consider printing the results of your data after one partitioning pass as a way to show yourself that it works. You'll develop testing skills that way. Anyway, once you have a working quicksort, then you can do things like separate pivot selection into a function and play with the implementation.

Good luck, and enjoy your project. Don't forget, though: We want timings, and especially time comparisons with the sort routine in the standard library!

Comment: All of that is in the assignment. For testing I was printing the pivot, the array after findPivot goes over the array, every swap that was made (that was a lot to go through) and then a comparison of the arrays before and after partitioning.

Comment: An assignment, then. Well, others have pointed out some specific bugs. One pattern of bug I see is a confusion of the integers which represent indexes into the array with the integers which represent the data to be sorted. So, for example, try renaming "pivot" to "pivot_index" and "pivot_value" in your code, and then you'll see most of the problems jump out at you. The same is true of your "start" and "end". Now, if instead you passed "start" and "interval size" then some of the math might be easier...

Comment: As it happens, it looks like the only flaw probably is in find_pivot looking outside the range.

Comment: Passing an interval size is a good idea, I already handed the assignment in, but I'll try putting that in to get it working for myself. My logic flow went hybridQuicksort will call partition, which calls findPivot to get the pivot and swap it to a[0], that way partition knows where it is and what it's value is. Then when partition is done it will swap a[0], the pivot, with the last low value swapped and then return that position.

Comment: That is what I'm kind of thinking. I'll do that in a bit, my head is going bahh right now.

http://pastebin.org/45363 My entire code if you want to run it.