# My Quicksort implementation does not sort correctly

Tags: java, quicksort

I have been looking around but my confusion remains. I changed some things which people suggested around here but that only made the code worse.

I am using this list as a test  `int [] testing = {5, 2, 9, 6, 1, 7, 8, 10, 4, 12, 3, 13, 11};`
and I am getting < 1  2  3  **5  4**  6  7  8  **10  9**  11  12  13  > as a result. (I made the errors bold)

My main quicksort method.

```
public static void quickieSorty(int[] array, int start, int end) {

     int pivot;
     pivot = originalPivot(array, start, end);

     if (start < end)
     { 
        pivot = originalPivot(array, start, end);
  
        quickieSorty(array, start, pivot - 1);
   
        quickieSorty(array, pivot + 1, end);
     }  
}
```

Partition (Here is were I changed some things inside the for loop, but that just made the list even less sorted).

```
private static int originalPivot (int[] array, int start, int end) {

    int pivotValue;
    int endOfList;
    int mid;

    mid = (start + end) / 2;

    swap(array, start, mid);

    pivotValue = array[start];

    endOfList = start;
    for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < pivotValue)
        {
           endOfList++;
           swap(array, endOfList, i);
        }
    }
    swap(array, start, endOfList);
    return endOfList; 
}
```

Swap is the generic swap code

```
private static void swap (int[] array, int a, int b) {

   int temp;

   temp = array[a];
   array[a] = array[b];
   array[b] = temp; 
}
```

I used my textbook and called a helper, but they told me they do not know for sure.
Any help is welcomed, thanks in advance for your time, and help!

Comment: At what size input does your quicksort stop working? Size 1 should work for instance.

Comment: refer this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407750/14343554).

Comment: If I put more than 3 numbers, it starts to fail. (If I misunderstood, I am sorry).

Comment: never debug with your full data. Hardcode a list of 1 element, as Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen suggests. If that works, increase the list size to 2. Step through the code: what happens? (and don't just tell us, this is for _you_ to discover what happens, and if it's doing the wrong thing, fix that thing, because you might not even need us if you debug properly). Then switch up to 3, and still step through the code. _now_ what happens, and how does that differ from what you expected, and when. Quicksort is a pretty concise set of steps: there are only so many places you can do things wrong.

Comment: I think the `endOfList++` operation is misplaced, it should be done after the swap not before in `originalPivot` method.

Comment: I also had trouble with quicksort, I do remember.

Comment: Understood Mike. I will attempt to do that, thank you. Debugging using steps instead of the whole thing is a really good advice.

Comment: Artur, I already attempted that before, but it also, somehow, makes the code un-sort things more. Thank you for your suggestion!